# after upgrade to Webpack 5 not able to access the menifest in copy-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

My config was working fine in webpack version `4.6.0` and webpack-assets-manifest version `3.1.1`

since I upgraded to webpack `5` and webpack-assets-manifest to `5`. I'm not getting value in my `manifestObject` it's just empty object

I suspect this is happening because transform function running before manifest is created
looked into the new documentation of webpack-assets-manifest but could not get it working

my goal is to access manifest value in transform function, but it looks like transform function is running before manifest is generated

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var SaveHashes = require('webpack-assets-manifest');

const manifest = new SaveHashes({
    entrypoints: true,
    entrypointsKey: 'entryPoints'
});
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: ['./src/apps/main'],
        games: ['./src/apps/games'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: assetsUrl,
        filename: 'assets/javascript/[name].[contenthash].js',
        chunkFilename: 'assets/javascript/[name].[contenthash].js'
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        manifest,
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: './views/**/*',
                to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                transform(content, path) {
                    // I want to access manifest here
                    // so that I can inject the final script(javascript bundle with content hash)
                    // in my view template
                    const manifestObject = JSON.parse(manifest);
                }
            }
        ])
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to export it like this

```
const ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin").WebpackManifestPlugin;

.....
  new ManifestPlugin({
            fileName: "asset-manifest.json",
            publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
            generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
                const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
                    manifest[ file.name ] = file.path;

                    return manifest;
                }, seed);
                const entrypointFiles = entrypoints.main.filter(
                    (fileName) => !fileName.endsWith(".map")
                );

                return {
                    files: manifestFiles,
                    entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
                };
            },
        }),
```

and it will work `WebpackManifestPlugin` is what you need